# Library not loaded libmysqlclient, macOS Sonoma

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby 2.5.1
macOS Sonoma Beta

Run

```
rails server
```

Error

`/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib (LoadError)`

i want run my ruby and rails app.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use mysql2 (0.5.5) Apple Silicon macOS Ventura (13.5.2) Ruby (3.1.4) by:

Removing the default brew formula of MySQL. This points to MySQL 8.1 which I am not using.

```bash
brew uninstall mysql
```

Installing and linking the formula for MySQL 8.0. This is safe because it should be the only one installed on your system.

```bash
brew install mysql@8.0
brew link mysql@8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

install

```
gem install bundler -v 2.3.26
```

uninstall all mysql gem

```
gem uninstall mysql2
```

and install again

```
bundler install
```